# Find Minimum of two given times in PHP

Tags: php

Can somebody help me compare two times and found out which one is less than other. by less I mean which one has older time than other.

Times are retrieved from database :

```
$time1 = strtotime($row[0]);
$time2 = strtotime($row2[0]);
```

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: moar details please, is that time a timestamp? for example

Comment: It's clear that you've made a real effort to do this yourself

Comment: try `if($time1>$time2)`

Comment: tag is datetime and you said times in text? if it is php datetime object it is simple : $d1 = new DateTime('2012-04-12 00:00:00');
$d2 = new DateTime('2012-04-10 00:00:00'); if($d1<$d2) ...

Comment: You should try adding some sample data.

Comment: This question isn't answered before I don't want their difference I need the minimum.

Comment: Just compare $time1 and $time2 as they are now integer values which can be easily compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your input dates into timestamps, then just subtract one from the other.

```
$timestampA = 1221672010;
$timestampB = 1221671010;
$diff       = $timestampA - $timestampB;

if ( $diff > 0 ) {
  // $timestampA date is after $timestampB date
} else if ( $diff < 0 ) {
  // $timestampA date is before $timestampB date
} else {
  // dates are equal
}
```

To convert string date into timestamp you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function.

Comment: Is there any advantage to taking one from the other, as opposed to checking if one is bigger?

Comment: He is already done this by using strtotime.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to know which date is earlier, you can simply compare them.

Here is an example from the Php manual :

```
$d1 = new DateTime('1492-01-01');

$d2 = new DateTime('1492-12-31');


var_dump($d1 < $d2);

var_dump($d1 > $d2);

var_dump($d1 == $d2);

?>
```

Results :

```
bool(true)

bool(false)

bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by 2 times you mean 2 dates.
You can always convert them to timestamp and them compare the two numbers.

for that you can use strtotime function

Answer (score 0):

If you mean time() for times data use min function: http://fr.php.net/min

Otherwise, http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$time1 = time();
$time2 = time()-3600;
var_dump(min($time1, $time2));
```

Or

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function witch returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

or if you have the date-time in string format you can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it before comparaison.

The smallest number is the oldest time !

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime(min(array($row[0], $row2[0])));
```

Gives you the earliest time.